# Blocking standard out from a NSTask-run program

Tags: cocoa, redirect, nstask

I am using NSTask with setStandardOutput to redirect the standard output of a command line tool to my program, so I can use it for processing. This works great but as a side result the tool's output gets shown as output when I run my program. I want to completely redirect it so it only goes to the NSPipe object I specify.

Is this possible? The below example shows output standard output but I would like to do this with standard error as well.

```
NSTask *ls=[[NSTask alloc] init];
NSPipe *pipe=[[NSPipe alloc] init];
NSFileHandle *handle;
NSString *string;

[ls setLaunchPath:@"/bin/ls"];
[ls setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-l",@"/System",nil]];
[ls setStandardOutput:pipe];
handle=[pipe fileHandleForReading];

[ls launch];

string=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[handle readDataToEndOfFile]
    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Are you really running `ls` as the sub-process or was that just an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Its just an example (: But as I mentioned in the Answer I solved the issue. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more testing and realized that the above code does what I want, and the output is not displayed when my program is run, so it looks like I have no problem after all. (: